# How to read combo box in WPF DataGridEditTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

I've to bind items source to the `ComboBox` at window load event which is in the wpf `DataGrid` `edititemtemplate`.  So, how can I call that `ComboBox` from code to bind data?

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.SelectionChanged += (a, b) =>
{
    comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
};
```